# Using $(this) in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript function like this

```
function select_term(e){ 
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (target.nodeType == 3) target = target.parentNode;

    console.log(target.innerHTML);
}
```

now I call this function

```
<a href="#" onclick='select_term()' style='text-decoration:none'>{{ descriptor.name|safe }}</a>
```

So this function is supposed to give me the innerHTML of this anchor element. In principle

```
$(this).innerHTML
```

would do the job, but I don't understand how I can access $(this) in the function?

My problem is that the solution above does not work in all cases, since the descriptor name can look like

```
<em>test1</em>test2
```

If the user clicks on test1 the javascript function prints out `test1`. If the user clicks on test2 the javascript function prints out `<em>test1</em>test2`. I want always `<em>test1</em>test2`, since I want the innerHTML of the anchor element.

Comment: `$` is a function that doesn't exist in the native JS environment. Some libraries include a `$` function though. Instead, just do `this.innerHTML`, unless you're using a library where that makes sense.

Comment: ...but to access the bound element, pass it. `onclick='select_term(this, event)'`. And then define the function as `function select_term(elem, event) {...` since `this` won't give you the element.

Comment: ...aside from all that, I can't tell what you want.

Comment: Don't use `this` if you're writing event listeners. The first parameter to an event listener is the event, with `target` being the bound element firing the event. If you use `currentTarget` it references the exact element (i.e. a child element) that's actually firing the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of wrong event property usage. When user clicks on `<em>` - `e.target` will be the `<em>` element, when on `<a>`(text `test2`) - `e.target` is `<a>`. To prevent such things you just need to use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property of the event. Try this :

```
function select_term(e){ 
    var target = e.currentTarget;
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the element reference to your function like `onclick='select_term(this)'`.

**Check below snippet for example:**

```js
function select_term(obj) {
  // Here 'obj' refers to the anchor element
  console.log(obj.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick='select_term(this)' style='text-decoration:none'>{{ descriptor.name|safe }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `onclick` function, `this` is the element, and `this.innerHTML` would give you its inner html.

Inside `select_term`, `this` is `window`, because you've called it without any context. See [how does the this keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) for more details.

`$` is an undefined variable. If you've defined it as jQuery, then `$(this)` would give you a jQuery object wrapped around whatever element `this` is. `$(this).innerHTML` would give you `undefined` because jQuery doesn't provide `innerHTML` (it does have the `html` *function* though).

If you want to get the `innerHTML` of the `a` element inside the `select_term` function, then you have to either:

- Write JavaScript that isn't mired in the '90s and use `addEventListener` instead of an `onclick` *attribute*
- Pass the element object to the `select_term` function

If you want to get the element using your first chunk of code, then you need to do the same thing, only with the event object.

The event handler function gets passed the event object as the first argument automatically, but the `onclick` function which calls the `select_term` function is the event handler. `select_term` itself is not.

```js
function select_term(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (target.nodeType == 3) target = target.parentNode;

  console.log(target.innerHTML);
}

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", select_term);
```

```html
<a href="#" style='text-decoration:none'>{{ descriptor.name|safe }}</a>
```

That said, you can just use `currentTarget` instead of all the fiddling you are currently using to try to identify the element.

```js
function select_term(e) {
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  console.log(target.innerHTML);
}

document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", select_term);
```

```html
<a href="#" style='text-decoration:none'>{{ descriptor.name|safe }}</a>
```

NB: If you're writing `href="#"` then you don't have a link and should not use `<a>`. Consider `<button type="button">...</button>` instead.

Comment: Using `this` does not necessarily point to the correct object.

Comment: @DissidentRage — It points to the object I said it would point to. I don't know what you mean by "correct object" or which of the possible uses of `this` in my answer you are referring to. My conclusion doesn't even use `this` anyway.

Comment: The link you've added requires further digestion on the part of the OP to understand how `this` works but in the meantime using `this` in event listeners is an unsafe practice. Edit: No, perhaps you aren't now, but you were using it.

Comment: It's perfectly safe to use `this` in event listeners. It usually gives undesirable (but understandable and consistent) results in *delegated* event handlers, but there's no use of delegation here.